# how identify ms access database using vb.net?

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I have MS access database for my application. Now I have zip the database and unzip the database using dotnetzip library. 
My question is when user restore the database how to identify the database it is my database or not ?

If it is my database then restore it otherwise restrict it using vb.net?
I want to copy all the item that unzip from source folder to destination folder.

How can do that?

I unzip the database and directly restore the database but when I select wrong database it is also restore the database and when I run my program it getting error.

Comment: You can calculate the MD5 checksum of each file beforehand and then compare that to the value you calculate after extraction.  If the checksums match, the files are the same.  That is why some sites that provide files for download also provide the MD5 checksum.  It's so that you can confirm that what you download is true to the original.

Comment: The error is probably a pretty good clue that it is not your database. You need to define the specific of what makes it YOUR database. Is this your database because it has the schema you expect or is it yours because it is the specific users data?